# i am trying to upload my data on sql server through my android app

Tags: php, android, sql

here is the android code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 String ServerURL = "http://portal15.unaux.com/get_data.php";

 EditText qr_code, desc,price ;

 Button button;

 String Tempqr, Tempdesc,Tempprice ;


  @Override

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 qr_code=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.code);

 desc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.resource);

 price=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);

 button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Getdata();
         insertdata(Tempqr,Tempdesc,Tempprice);
     }
    // converting input data to string
    public void Getdata(){

        Tempqr = qr_code.getText().toString();
        Tempdesc=desc.getText().toString();
        Tempprice = price.getText().toString();

    }

     public void insertdata(final String code, final String description,final String price){

         class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                 String qrHolder = code;
                 String descHolder = description ;
                 String priceHolder=price;

                 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", qrHolder));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", descHolder));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", priceHolder));
                 try {
                     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

                     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                     HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                 } catch (IOException e) {

                 }
                 return "Data Inserted Successfully";
             }

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                 super.onPostExecute(result);

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
         }

         SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

         sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(code,description,price);
     }
 });
 }

}
```

Data is not uploading in mysql database but a toast is displaying on my phone saying data uploaded successfully but no data is uploaded on server.

Here is my PHP Code

```
<?php include 'DatabaseConfig.php'; 
$con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName); 
$code = $_POST['code']; 
$details = $_POST['description']; 
$price=$_POST['price']; 
$Sql_Query="INSERT INTO item_details (item_code, item_details, Item_price) 
VALUES(' $code ',' $details ',' $price')"; 
if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)) { 
    echo 'Data Submitted Successfully'; 
} 
else { 
    echo 'Try Again'; 
} 
mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: So whats the question ?

Comment: data is not uploading in mysql database toast is displayin on my phone as data uploaded sucessfully but no data is uploaded on server.

Comment: here is php code
<?php
    include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;

    $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
 
    $code = $_POST['code'];

    $details = $_POST['description'];
    
    $price=$_POST['price'];

    $Sql_Query="INSERT INTO item_details (item_code, item_details, Item_price)    VALUES(' $code ',' $details ',' $price')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){ 
 
      echo 'Data Submitted Successfully';
 
                 }
     else{
 
       echo 'Try Again';
 
         }

    mysqli_close($con); 

 ?>

Comment: One suggestion just leave `HttpClient` and use a Network library [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) probably. and do not add code in comments Edit your question to explain the problem .

Comment: can u send me a code using retrofit i have not used this api before?

Comment: Just follow the link i have attached above.

Comment: That's good that you want. But what is the problem?

Comment: please check your server side code.. if you can show it here then please do the same.. i can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple and Easy** way to register(save) data into database

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etFullName, etUserName, etPassword, etPhone, etEmail;
private Button clickbut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullName);
    etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    /*clickbut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Show);
    clickbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launch();
        }
    });*/
}

public void signup(View v) {
    String fullName = etFullName.getText().toString();
    String userName = etUserName.getText().toString();
    String passWord = etPassword.getText().toString();
    String phoneNumber = etPhone.getText().toString();
    String emailAddress = etEmail.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new SignupActivity(this).execute(fullName, userName, passWord, phoneNumber, emailAddress);

    etFullName.setText("");//clear all the fields after button click
    etUserName.setText("");
    etPassword.setText("");
    etPhone.setText("");
    etEmail.setText("");
}

/*public void launch(){
    new Show_details(this).execute();
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,ShowActvity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}*/
```

}

Above is mainActivity for getting user data and passing it to AsyncTask class (here it is SignupActivity.java)

```
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String >{

private Context context;
public SignupActivity(Context context){
    this.context =context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String fullName = arg0[0];
    String userName = arg0[1];
    String passWord = arg0[2];
    String phoneNumber = arg0[3];
    String emailAddress = arg0[4];

    String link;
    String data;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String result;
    try {
        data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
        data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
        data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

        link = "http://192.168.43.212/signup.php" + data;
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        result = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (result.equals("Registration Successfull")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Registration Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

}

Here i passed the values to signup.php by using GET method, signup.php file:

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","rohan","rohan","singup");
 mysqli_connect_errno($con);

 $fullName = $_GET['fullname'];
 $userName = $_GET['username'];
 $passWord = $_GET['password'];
 $phoneNumber = $_GET['phonenumber'];
 $emailAddress = $_GET['emailaddress'];

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user (fullname, username, 
 password, phone, email) VALUES ('$fullName', '$userName', '$passWord', '$phoneNumber', '$emailAddress')");


if($result == true) {
    echo "Registration Successfull";
}
else{
    echo "Registration Unsuccessfull";
}

mysqli_close($con);?>
```

For calling singup method in MainActivity,I have given onClick value to (singup)button in layout file(.xml) of MainActivity

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSignup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="signup"
android:text="Sign up" />
```

I hope this will help you,and suggest that instead of using Asynctask for making Http calls use another like Volley and Retrofit for easy and faster connection...